# use multiple screens on a window - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to use multiple screens ( `panel` or anything else ) on a window!

i don't want to use `MDI Child Form` ...

Is there another way?
[image]

## or

[image]

Comment: There is UserControls.

Comment: what do you want use usercontrol and show hide on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our approach to this is to create the "views" as `UserControl`s and then add/remove them in code to/from a panel on the form. Most times they share a set of common methods (interface `IView`) so we can for example check whether a view as unsaved data, etc.

Answer (score 3):

For the second scenario that you show you can use a Tab control with the tabs displayed vertically:

Add a TabControl to your form.

Set the Alignment property to Right.

Set the SizeMode property to Fixed, so that all tabs are the same width.

Set the ItemSize property to the preferred fixed size for the tabs. Keep in mind that the ItemSize property behaves as though the tabs were on top, although they are right-aligned. As a result, in order to make the tabs wider, you must change the Height property, and in order to make them taller, you must change the Width property.

In the code example below, Width is set to 25 and Height is set to 150.

Set the DrawMode property to OwnerDrawFixed.

Define a handler for the DrawItem event of TabControl that renders the text from left to right.

```
private void TabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush _TextBrush = default(Brush);

        // Get the item from the collection. 
    TabPage _TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(e.Index);

    // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle. 
    Rectangle _TabBounds = TabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

    if ((e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)) 
        {
        // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
        _TextBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
    } 
        else 
        {
        _TextBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
        e.DrawBackground();
    }

    // Use our own font. 
    Font _TabFont = new Font("Arial", 10.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // Draw string. Center the text. 
    StringFormat _StringFlags = new StringFormat();
    _StringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    _StringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    g.DrawString(_TabPage.Text, _TabFont, _TextBrush, _TabBounds, new StringFormat(_StringFlags));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Tab control. Hope it suits your requirement.